# respond_to json gives error: no route matches "/schedules/list.json" with {:method=>:get}

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie trying to make a webservice that talks JSON. I have this
in my controller:

`class SchedulesController < ApplicationController

  def list

    @schedules = Schedules.all

    respond_to do |format|

      format.html # list.html.erb

      format.json { render :json => @schedules.to_json }

    end

  end

end`

I have nothing special in my routes, only the default:

`ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

end`

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Thank you
Søren

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the default "index" action instead of "list"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 map.connect ':controller/:action.:format'
```